# Getting error while enabling casemanager in IBM Business Automation Workflow

Tags: business-process-management, ibm-bpm, ibm-case-manager

I have installed IBM Business automation workflow on my local and trying to enable CaseManager, as per the knowledge center when I try to execute below command. It throws error

```
print AdminTask.createObjectStoreForContent(['-clusterName', 'AppCluster', '-PEWorkflowSystemAdminGroup', 'adminGroup2','-creationUser','deadmin','-password','deadmin_pw'])
```

Error

com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException
org.apache.soap.SOAPException: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=com.filenet.api.exception.EngineRuntimeException
Server stack trace
JMXTransformException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.filenet.api.exception.EngineRuntimeException